# Which are the stock Gnome apps not included in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome

I would like to know which stock gnome apps are not included in Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider to be "stock" GNOME apps?

Comment: I'm referring to those apps that are part of the vanilla gnome shell.

Comment: The vanilla GNOME Shell is ... just the shell.

Comment: OK, so apps like Evolution, Gnome Weather or Gnome Music are not part of a core Gnome Package.

Comment: Is there a definitive list of "core"/"stock" GNOME apps? If you can provide a list, then I believe others will be able to tell which ones are included and which ones are not. I found [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Core_Applications) , but I'm not sure how up-to-date or correct it is.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a metapackage named "gnome-core":

```
$ apt show gnome-core
Package: gnome-core
Version: 1:3.22+9
Priority: optional
Section: universe/gnome
Source: meta-gnome3
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers <pkg-gnome-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 32.8 kB
Depends: libatk-adaptor (>= 2.22), at-spi2-core (>= 2.22), adwaita-icon-theme, baobab (>= 3.22), fonts-cantarell (>= 0.0.25), caribou (>= 0.4.21), dconf-cli (>= 0.26), dconf-gsettings-backend (>= 0.26), eog (>= 3.20), evince (>= 3.22), evolution-data-server (>= 3.22), sound-theme-freedesktop, gdm3 (>= 3.22), gedit (>= 3.22), glib-networking (>= 2.50), gnome-backgrounds (>= 3.22), gnome-bluetooth (>= 3.20), gnome-calculator (>= 3.22), gnome-characters (>= 3.22), gnome-contacts (>= 3.22), gnome-control-center (>= 1:3.22), gnome-disk-utility (>= 3.22), gnome-font-viewer (>= 3.22), gnome-keyring (>= 3.20), libpam-gnome-keyring (>= 3.20), gnome-logs (>= 3.22), gnome-menus (>= 3.13), gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.22), gnome-online-miners (>= 3.22), gnome-session (>= 3.22), gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.22), gnome-shell (>= 3.22), gnome-shell-extensions (>= 3.22), gnome-software (>= 3.22), gnome-system-monitor (>= 3.22), gnome-terminal (>= 3.22), gnome-themes-extra (>= 3.22), gnome-user-docs (>= 3.22), gnome-user-share (>= 3.18), gsettings-desktop-schemas (>= 3.22), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base (>= 1.10), gstreamer1.0-plugins-good (>= 1.10), gstreamer1.0-packagekit, gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio (>= 1.10), gvfs-backends (>= 1.30), gvfs-bin (>= 1.30), gvfs-fuse (>= 1.30), firefox-esr (>= 30) | firefox (>= 30) | chromium | chromium-browser, libcanberra-pulse, libproxy1-plugin-gsettings, gkbd-capplet (>= 3.22), nautilus (>= 3.22), pulseaudio, system-config-printer-common, system-config-printer-udev, gnome-sushi (>= 3.20), totem (>= 3.22), tracker, yelp (>= 3.22), zenity (>= 3.22)
Recommends: network-manager-gnome, libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager, anacron
...
Description: GNOME Desktop Environment -- essential components

$
```

If you clean up the list of `depends`, you can run `apt policy` on the list and pipe the output to `grep` to figure what's missing on your system:

```
apt policy adwaita-icon-theme  at-spi2-core baobab caribou chromium chromium-browser dconf-cli dconf-gsettings-backend eog evince evolution-data-server firefox firefox-esr fonts-cantarell gdm3 gedit gkbd-capplet glib-networking gnome-backgrounds gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-keyring gnome-logs gnome-menus gnome-online-accounts gnome-online-miners gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-software gnome-sushi gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-themes-extra gnome-user-docs gnome-user-share gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-fuse libatk-adaptor libcanberra-pulse libpam-gnome-keyring libproxy1-plugin-gsettings nautilus pulseaudio sound-theme-freedesktop system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev totem tracker yelp zenity  | grep -B1 Installed
```

Here's a partial output on my system (which is Kubuntu 18.04):

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

adwaita-icon-theme:
  Installed: 3.28.0-1ubuntu1
--
at-spi2-core:
  Installed: 2.28.0-1
--
baobab:
  Installed: (none)
--
caribou:
  Installed: (none)
--
chromium:
  Installed: (none)
--
chromium-browser:
  Installed: (none)
--
dconf-cli:
  Installed: (none)
--
dconf-gsettings-backend:
  Installed: 0.26.0-2ubuntu3
--
eog:
  Installed: (none)
--
evince:
  Installed: (none)
--
evolution-data-server:
  Installed: (none)
```

In a [comment to this answer, muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046478/which-are-the-stock-gnome-apps-not-included-in-ubuntu-18-04/1046502#comment1707175_1046502) has mentioned the fact that some applications are installed as snaps, at least in 18.04. There's also a mention of snaps being installed by default in [Why have Canonical installed core Gnome apps as Snaps by default?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1039968/248158).

In the case of the snaps listed in the question linked to above, four of them are also listed in the output of `apt show gnome-core`. Two, `gnome-3-26-1604` and `gtk-common-themes` aren't.

Anyway, snaps installed on the system can be seen by running `snap list` according to https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#2.

Comment: Good idea, but there's still the problem of [some GNOME apps being installed via snaps](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#New_since_17.10-1).

Comment: @muru, I don't know how to get around the issue of snaps and didn't even consider that possibility!