# Dark theme not used by all applications - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, themes

A lot of applications (including ubuntu default apps such as system monitor, calculator, logs, etc. as well as other third party applications) do not apply the dark theme.

How to force all applications to use the defined dark theme? Or, is it possible to delete all other themes in the computer, so that all apps are forced to use the only one that exists?

Comment: For removing Snap applications also see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1050152/66509).