# What does snap/gnome-3-26-1604 do? Can it be removed without breaking Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, snap

I recently found `/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/` on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 machine. I found [this other related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039968/why-have-canonical-installed-core-gnome-apps-as-snaps-by-default), but not much else to explain what it is used for. I also seem to have several versions of it: `/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70`, `/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74` and `/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/current`.

What does this snap do? And can it be removed without breaking anything significant?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It should be this snap: https://snapcraft.io/gnome-3-26-1604

> This snap includes a GNOME 3.26 stack (the base libraries and desktop
>   integration components) and shares it through the content interface.

So, unless you have another gnome stack in usage, you should not remove it.

Edit: As snap always downloads a whole new version instead of updating and does not auto-delete the old ones, yes, you can delete the old ones. Check which are disabled with `snap list --all`  and remove with `snap remove --revision XXX gnome-3-26-1604` where XXX is the revision number (eg 70).

Comment: Alright, thanks. I guess it would be safe to remove the older versions and just leave the current? I was going through the gnome snaps to remove and install the apt ones instead since themes doesn't work with the snap ones.

Comment: Yes, see my edit in the answer.

Comment: Perfect, now the answer completely answers the question. Thank you!

Comment: I tried `$ snap remove gnome-3-34-1804 --revision=77;
> error: cannot remove "gnome-3-34-1804": cannot remove active revision 77 of snap "gnome-3-34-1804"
`

Comment: It seems like some libraries still need the old gnove stacks; related: [how-do-i-find-out-which-snaps-are-using-which-versions-of-the-runtime](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278364)