# How do I find out which snaps are using which versions of the runtime

Tags: snap

I have Gnome 3.26, 3.28 and 3.34 on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04) and want to know if I can get rid of any of them to save disk space. Is there some kind of `snap` command I can run that will show me?

Comment: Probably, there is a command that allows you to see details on a snap, including which other snaps it would need. The full documentation of snap is here: https://snapcraft.io/docs

Comment: Yes, I expect there probably there is. And I would like to know what it is. Hence my question! `snap info <snap-name> --verbose` doesn't give me that dependency info.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your question. By definition, snaps are self-contained binary blobs, so there are no external dependencies. This is by design. However, if you're asking whether you can safely delete snaps such that their removal won't adversely impact your Linux environment, the command to run would be `sudo snap services` which lists active services employed via snaps. For validation, you can also run `sudo systemctl status snap.<service name>`. I hope that helps answer your question.

Comment: How do you get the list of Gnome versions?

Comment: @cachius `snap list` gives you the list of snaps - and I see I now have Gnome 3.38 and Gnome 42 as well on my machine! But I first spotted this looking at disk space usage.

Comment: @richbi running `sudo snap services` lists a canonical live patch service and a desktop integration thing - but nothing that says "gnome". My question was - as you have I think worked out - is "what will happen if I delete these gnome snaps?". I think the answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155957/two-different-versions-of-gnome-runtime. Bur I still don't know where these snaps came from or what ubuntu software relies on them.

Comment: On [my answer](http://www.scielo.org.ar/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1851-17402003000100005) I mention that [`gnome-...` snaps are just backends for GTK snap apps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1345181/349837). If you don't use snaps you can remove them. Also "it's possible to remove all the snaps, and remove snapd... the desktop will function fine" (from Popey, former snap developer; now developer of [unsnap](https://github.com/popey/unsnap)).

Answer (score 4):

#### Snap Commands to track connections

- You may use command below to list all slots/plugs used.

  ```
  snap connections
  ```

  or for specific app, example:

  ```
  $ snap connections snap-store
  Interface                 Plug                                      Slot                             Notes
  appstream-metadata        snap-store:appstream-metadata             :appstream-metadata              -
  content[gnome-3-38-2004]  snap-store:gnome-3-38-2004                gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004  -
  content[gtk-3-themes]     snap-store:gtk-3-themes                   gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes   -
  content[icon-themes]      snap-store:icon-themes                    gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    -
  content[sound-themes]     snap-store:sound-themes                   gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   -
  dbus                      -                                         snap-store:packagekit-svc        -
  dbus                      -                                         snap-store:snap-store            -
  desktop                   snap-store:desktop                        :desktop                         -
  desktop-legacy            snap-store:desktop-legacy                 :desktop-legacy                  -
  ...
  ```

  or probably best option with reverse search:

  ```
  $ snap connections gnome-3-38-2004 
  Interface                 Plug                                       Slot                             Notes
  content[gnome-3-38-2004]  firefox:gnome-3-38-2004                    gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004  -
  content[gnome-3-38-2004]  snap-store:gnome-3-38-2004                 gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004  -
  content[gnome-3-38-2004]  snapd-desktop-integration:gnome-3-38-2004  gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004
  ```
- It may be worth adding, search by interface too:

  ```
  $ snap interface content | grep gnome
    - firefox:gnome-3-38-2004
    - snap-store:gnome-3-38-2004
    - snapd-desktop-integration:gnome-3-38-2004
    - gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004
  ```

#### Explaining snap connection

Due to the objective nature of snaps. Snap runs regular apps in confined environment. So each snap app that depends on another app, its developer has to declare the "connection" (or we may say plug-slot), [mook765's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1439248/26246) here has used it for his approach (`snap.yaml` contains the dependencies declaration). The type of the connection is called "interface" `content[gnome-3-38-2004]`. And each connection composed of (one "slot" which is connected to either no, one or many "plugs"). Slot `gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004` in this case is provided by gnome core snap, app declares and uses a plug ex:`snap-store:gnome-3-38-2004` to that slot.

A good reference to read more: [snapcraft.io: gnome-3-38-extension - plugs](https://snapcraft.io/docs/gnome-3-38-extension#heading--plugs)

#### Removing gnome-extension snap (Test)

Connections may auto/manually be connected or disconnected, that why I expect snap doesn't force uninstalling of dependent apps. I tested it within Ubuntu 22.04 in Virtual-box. Snap disconnects plug/slot and then removes the app. The app fails to run anyway.

```
$ snap remove gnome-3-38-2004
gnome-3-38-2004 removed

$ snap connections snap-store 
Interface                 Plug                                      Slot                            Notes
appstream-metadata        snap-store:appstream-metadata             :appstream-metadata             -
content                   snap-store:gnome-3-38-2004                -                               -
content[gtk-3-themes]     snap-store:gtk-3-themes                   gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes  -
content[icon-themes]      snap-store:icon-themes                    gtk-common-themes:icon-themes   -
content[sound-themes]     snap-store:sound-themes                   gtk-common-themes:sound-themes  -
dbus                      -                                         snap-store:packagekit-svc       -
...

$ snap-store
ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-38-2004 content interface.

$ firefox
ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-38-2004 content interface.
```

Comment: Interesting. So, for your example, it looks like the `gnome-3-38-2004` snap is used for the `firefox`, `snap-store` and `snapd-desktop-integration` snaps. If you were to remove the gnome snap, presumably those other 3 snaps would be affected/break/need to be uninstalled as well. Do I have that right?

Comment: BTW, I have no idea what connections, interfaces, plugs or slots are when it comes to snaps. I thought a snap was just a different way if installing software - so all these other terms are brand new to me. I guess I'd need to read the docs... Thanks for your help

Comment: @charlesdeb You are right however  you don't have to remove dependent apps, but they may have limited/partial functionality or completely break. (I didn't test it, i will soon, I have Ubuntu in a virtualbox).

Comment: @charlesdeb About idioms, Snap create  isolated runtime environment for each app. So each app needs another app, its developer  has to declare the "connection", type of connection is called  "interface". And each connection composed of (1 "slot" and  0 or many "plugs"). Slot in this case is provided by gnome core snap, each app that depend on gnome, declare and use a plug to that slot.

Comment: so why is firefox and chrome also using such an old library from 2004?

Comment: @rubo77 Snap core is built after releasing Ubuntu. So they are released and updated in sequence: Ubuntu 22.04 -> core22 -> Apps migration. They are kind of slow in stable channel, only if some prefer installing from edge channel.

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to list the base (core18, core20, core22, and so on).

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the dependencies of a snap by examining it's `snap.yaml`-file which is

```
/snap/<snapname>/<revision>/meta/snap.yaml
```

The commands

```
~$ grep "default-provider:" /snap/*/*/meta/snap.yaml
~$ grep "base:" /snap/*/*/meta/snap.yaml
```

will produce a list of all needed dependencies for all installed snaps, a dependency not listed can safely be removed. See the example in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236201/590937).