# Is it safe to remove gnome snap packages while uninstalling snapd?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, snap

I would like to get rid of snap forever and found a very nice manual for that. However, I wonder if it has any bad consequences to uninstall the last remaining snap applications on my computer.

```
snap list

Name                 Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher     Notes
canonical-livepatch  9.6.2                       99     latest/stable    canonical✓    -
core                 16-2.50.1                   11167  latest/stable    canonical✓    core
core18               20210507                    2066   latest/stable    canonical✓    base
gnome-3-28-1804      3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gnome-3-34-1804      0+git.3556cb3               72     latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes    0.1-52-gb92ac40             1515   latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
snap-store           3.38.0-63-g766b86f          542    latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
snapd                2.50.1                      12057  latest/stable    canonical✓    snapd
```

Can anybody explain me the consequences of uninstalling stuff such as core, core18, gnome or gtk-common-themes? Do they need to be present on my computer by installing them via apt afterwards? Since it says gnome, I am in fear of losing the graphical interface directly afterwards.

Comment: I'm not a GNOME user, but in my testing & experience, there are no real consequences but it's not as simple as you'll likely hope.  Upgrades into the future, plus your own commands (unless you consider the consequences of commands before hand) can cause snap services to restart or be re-installed. You may have to revert the changes before *release-upgrade* time (though they maybe automatically reverted) and there are some functions you cannot use without snap (eg. your paste shows one!)

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Yeah, I never used livepatches anyway. And there is a command to prevent reinstallation of snap. I will see how it works, thanks for naming your concerns

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The packages `gnome-3-34-1804` and `gnome-3-28-1804` are **not** the GNOME desktop environment you are using. They are the GNOME backends for GTK snap apps. You can safely remove them, if you intend to remove other snap apps. [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035917/124466) answer explains how to.

That won't affect your GNOME desktop environment (which is installed as a .deb package through apt, and you **don't** need to reinstall it.)

Comment: The linked answer is actually the manual I was referring to above. Wonderful, thank you for your explanation.