# Multiple GNOMEs

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-software

I was on gnome software and saw this:
[GNOME 3.2.8 Runtime| gnome-3-38-2004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMpU8.png)

Are these the same things? Do I need both?

Comment: Looks like snaps, you can check with `snap list` which snaps are installed. If they are snaps, then they are needed by other installed snaps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to remove gnome snap packages while uninstalling snapd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345156/removing-snap-reinstalling-gnome)

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release; but on my release what you provided reminds me of a requirement of `firefox` snap package; ie. using `snap connections firefox` will show details of connections/requirements for *snap* packages